# On Saving the Object in session throws illegalArgumentException in class XXXX

Tags: java, hibernate, session, oracle10g

I am Trying save an object in session as **session.save(object)** but it is raising the illegal argument exception and also raising as **expected type: java.lang.Long, actual value: java.lang.Long**

in what scenarios these type of exception will raise? please help me out ,i searched a lot but i couldn't find the solution

Stack Trace:

```
2013-11-26 14:51:59,646 ERROR http-8081-4 org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor - IllegalArgumentException in class: org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.AssessmentBaseData, setter method of property: assessmentBaseId
2013-11-26 14:51:59,661 ERROR http-8081-4 org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor - expected type: java.lang.Long, actual value: java.lang.Long
```

AssessmentBaseData.java

```
public class AssessmentBaseData
    implements java.io.Serializable,
               org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.ifc.assessment.AssessmentBaseIfc
{

 private Long assessmentBaseId;
 private String title;

public AssessmentBaseData(Long assessmentBaseId, String title){
    this.assessmentBaseId = assessmentBaseId;
    this.title = title;

}

public String getTitle() {
    return this.title;
  }

  public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
  }

public Long getAssessmentBaseId() {
    return this.assessmentBaseId;
  }

  public void setAssessmentBaseId(Long assessmentBaseId) {


    this.assessmentBaseId = assessmentBaseId;
  }
  }
}
```

a part of hbm file

```
<hibernate-mapping default-lazy="false">
  <class name="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.AssessmentBaseData"
    table="SAM_ASSESSMENTBASE_T">
    <id name="assessmentBaseId" column="ID" type="java.lang.Long" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="native">
        <param name="sequence">SAM_ASSESSMENTBASE_ID_S</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
```

I'm using Oracle 10g Database, Tomcat 6 application server, hibernate 3.0 version

Comment: Please provide your full stack trace. It´s easier to understand.

Comment: I would guess that the object you are trying to save has a problem with it´s identity, are you providing both getter and setter methods for the Id?

Comment: If you provide a codesnippet of AssessmentBaseData.class then it would be easier

Comment: I belive this answer also will solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050996/expected-type-java-lang-integer-actual-value-org-hibernate-id-identifiergener

Comment: i also tried by changing the generator as sequence or increment but it did not solve my problem @Marthin

Comment: in what way are you generating your id? provide xml or annotations please.

Comment: Try removing this: unsaved-value="0". You are using java.lang.Long and not the primitive type 'long'. It should be 'null' but as this is the default just remove it.

Comment: ok sure @AlanHay i will try now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide a default constructor to your AssessmentBaseData.class

```
public AssessmentBaseData(){}
```

Comment: In my AssessmentBaseData class i already consists default constructor I provided above is the snippet code of my class to get overview for u

Comment: please provide me the solution Marthin i am facing this problem since two days even i can't find the solution